# Stability of an unstable system using nonlinear element. Is it possible or not?

Tags: control-system

Say there is an system with open-loop transfer function $$G(s)=\frac{1}{s-1}$$
The system is definitely unstable.

If I put an any nonlinear system in cascade with \$G(s)\$ & from the output, a negative unity feedback. Is it possible to make the system close-loop transfer function is stable? It is assumed that the higher order harmonics are filtered in the close loop path.

Comment: Why do mention "any nonlinear system"? Is an additional linear feedback block not allowed?

Comment: May be. But my intention is not to make a liner system stable by using liner element, but using a nonlinear element.

Comment: Well if the linearized small signal transfer function including the non-linear element is stable at every operating point along the non-linear element's characteristic then the overall system should be stable.  Every practical control system in the world is evidence of this since there's no such thing as a perfectly linear element.

Comment: Then please give me an example where a unstable system becomes stable using nonlinear element. @JohnD

Comment: Conference: Applied Power Electronics Conference, APEC 2007 - Twenty Second Annual IEEE
Source: IEEE Xplore
ABSTRACT Digital controller provides capability to implement flexible control algorithm. The nonlinear PID function with power coefficients is proposed in this paper.....  "Nonlinear PID in Digital Controlled Buck Converters"

Comment: I have a bachelor's degree in engineering. To my knowledge, we never, not once, studied formal stability of non-linear systems using this type of analysis. AFAIK, all the theoretical stability analysis using poles and zeroes and Laplace transforms (s domain) is only valid on linear systems. That being said, it is not too hard to think of a case where a marginally stable system can be improved with a non-linear element. For example, if you have a sharp rising edge, overshoot can be clamped with a diode to greatly reduce ringing. But simulation would normally be done using transient analysis.

Comment: Thanks, mkeith, that is the physical point of view. But is it possible to derive it mathematically, I mean by satisfying Nyquist criterion?

Comment: I have never seen any theoretical presentation of stability theory that dealt with nonlinear systems. That doesn't mean no such thing exists. But when I studied stability, at the beginning of the class, the professor emphasized that we were studying linear time invariant systems.

Comment: Stability is almost always approximated as a linear analysis because any non-linear system can be approximated by a linear one within a small region about an equilibrium (see: Taylor Series). A system violates linear stability first before it becomes unstable; further unstable growth may occur non-linearly, but once it's gone unstable you usually don't care that much. If the system is able to settle to a new "stable" equilibrium, simply repeat the linear analysis again for the new equilibrium.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect a simple linear gain, K, in series with the 1/(s-1) block, giving a transfer function: K/(s-1), and then form a negative feedback closed loop system around this new block, the closed loop transfer function will be K/[s+(K-1)], which is stable if K>1.

Another simple block that is unstable in the open loop is an integrator, which has transfer function: 1/s. It's easy to see that this is unstable by considering a unit step input. This will result in a unit ramp output (integral of a constant, A, is ramp, At), and this goes to infinity for large t. However, closing the loop around the integrator (with or without a series gain, K) will give a stable closed loop with transfer function: K/(s+K), or 1/(s+1). As well as being stable, the closed loop system has unity steady state gain (or 'DC gain'), which is characteristic of closed loop systems that have a pure integrator in the forward path transfer function.

Comment: Where is non-linear element?

Comment: You could have a non-linear gain which is dependent on the instantaneous error signal magnitude, say, E(t). Perhaps: K=(1+E(t))^2. But why would the element need to be nonlinear in the first place? Normally we try to make things as linear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

We have a system with the response $$G(s)={1\over s-1},$$ and we'd like a system with an arbitary (say: stable) reponse $$H(s)=H_2(s)H_1(s)G(s).$$ We presume that we can add the blocks H1 and H2, in that order, into the loop, after G.

Now suppose that H2 alone is linear and would give a stable response. But first, H1 would undo the effects of G - it would be the inverse response to G. Depending on G, H1 might need to be nonlinear. The hand-wavey part is that I'm not sure whether the composition H(s) can be written as above if H1 is nonlinear. If it can, then there's your answer, and you have the steps needed to do it:

1. Set H1 to be the inverse of G.
2. Set H2 to the stable open loop response you want.

Of course all of this might be a bunch of granola, as I haven't dealt with s domain in ages :/